# Can I force install cumulative update across Windows 10 version? And should I?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, setup

What if I download .wsu of the latest cumulative of latest Windows 10 version in...

[Windows 10 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018124)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4018124

then I manually install it by

`wusa.exe file.wsu`

Can I do this **across** Windows 10 version? (i.e. non-latest versions e.g., 1507, 1511, 1607)
    - If yes, should I do this way to update to latest cumulative of lastest Windows 10 version?
    - If no, how to properly update any Windows 10 machine to latest cumulative of lastest Windows 10 version by offline means? (i.e. Is having a latest copy of ISO always a must?)

Comment: use WSUS to manage updates

Comment: @magicandre1981: Do you mean that I should replace wusa.exe with wsus.exe in the question?

Comment: @magicandre1981: I see you mean "Windows Server Update Services." Unfortunately I have no access to Windows Server environment. Anyway, thank for your suggestion.

Comment: yes I mean Windows Server Update Services.

Answer (score 0):

For cumulative update. You have to check with https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Windows%2010%20 cumulative%20update or Windows Update catalog for Windows 10 build product version. For example, 2023-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5029244) will support products Windows 10, version 1903 and later, Windows 10 LTSB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just curious if there are some ways not having to have the whole big ISO all the time when working offline. Unfortunately it seems not likely.

Comment: Main reason why you cannot work on offline updates is because each updates is difference even in similar update. For example, cumulative update of Windows 10 version 1607 will different from cumulative update of Windows 10 version 1703. (Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq)